# Explicit description for dual to operator space of Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-norms, operator-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, and $B := \mathcal B(H)$ be the space of bounded operators on $H$.

1. It is known that $B^\ast_\mathrm{strong} = B^\ast_\mathrm{weak}$ (see [Dunford, Schwartz, VI.1.4]).
2. In the uniform setting, there is a complete description for the subset of positive normalized functionals in $B^\ast_\mathrm{uniform}$; see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.4213/mzm9085) for reference ([English translation](https://doi.org/10.1134%2FS0001434613030012)).

I am looking for some sort of description of the whole space $B^\ast_\mathrm{uniform}$. I know that this space is very large, but may be there is some sort of normal form for the elements of $B^\ast_\mathrm{uniform}$.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding something in the question. Every bounded linear functional on $B_{\operatorname{uniform}}$ is a complex linear combination of at most four positive fumctionals, so why doesn't your reference already answer your question?

Comment: As you probably know, the dual in the first case can be identified in a natural way, with the nuclear operators.  As you say, the norm dual is vastly larger.  You can get some idea of how large it can be by considering the commutative cases--$\ell^\infty$ and $L^\infty$  where there are such representations (as finitely additive measures or, in the first case, as measures on the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta N$.   The non-commutative case is even more complicated and I am unaware of any explicit representatons.  By the way, this is one of the many reasons why the norm structure is

Comment: too strong for a number of situations--hence the introduction of variants--the weak, srtrong, ultraweak, ultrastrong topologies and their starred version.  To make my observation above more precise, the duals in the first cases are the finite rank operators, in the second the nuclear ones (and this is equivalent to being normal in the positive case).  A good reference is the classic text by Dixmier.